# Bound involving $H^1$-norm : $|v(x)| ≤ C \cdot ||v||_{H^1(a,b)}$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis

I'm trying to prove the following result :

> For all $v \in H^1(a,b)$, there exists a positive constant $C>0$ such that $$|v(x)| ≤  C  \cdot ||v||_{H^1(a,b)} \quad ∀x ∈ [a, b].$$

Here we defined $||v||_{H^1(a,b)} := 
\left(\int_a^b |v(x)|^2  \text{dx}+ \int_a^b |v'(x)|^2 \text{dx} \right)^{1/2}$.

I wrote $$ |v(x)| = \left|v(a) + \int_a^x v'(t) \text{dt} \right|
 ≤ |v(a)| + \int_a^b |v'(t)| \text{dt}
 ≤ |v(a)| + \sqrt{b-a} ||v||_{H^1(a,b)} $$ (using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality)
but I don't know how to get rid of the $|v(a)|$ term. The constant $C$ can depend on $v$, this can help, but I don't know how.

Any comment or answer will be appreciated !

Comment: Isn't $|v(a)|$ a (fix) nonnegative number? Then you could express it as some nonnegative constant times $||v||_{H^1}$ and be done, right? Or is that not allowed because that would generate a constant dependent on $a$?

Comment: @A.Sh : Oh yes ! That was so easy ! Thank you !

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality as stated is not correct. Indeed if $v$ is a constant nonzero function, then 
$$0< |v(x) | \le C \| v\|_{H^1(a, b)} = 0$$

and there is no $C$ that helps you deal with this, even if $C$ depends on $v$.

Indeed you need to either:

- specialize to $v(a) = 0$, in this case your proof works, or
- define $\|v\|^2_{H^1(a, b)} = \int_a^b |v(x)|^2 dx + \int_a^b |v'(x)|^2 dx$. Indeed this is more common as your $\| \cdot \|_{H^1(a, b)}$ is not a norm.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I had indeed forgotten some terms in the $|| \cdot ||_{H^1(a,b)}$  norm !